Manual replication of exact extract results
I am trying to better understand how exact extract works.
For this reason, I am trying to manually replicate the results obtained by this function.
Consider the following toy example. I create the shapefile of US states, and generate a raster from this shapefile. To each pixel of the raster I associate a unique value. Then, I exact extract the sum and the average values of the pixels falling within each state:
# load libraries
library(sf)
library(maps)
library(dplyr)
library(terra)
library(stars)
library(tidyterra)
library(exactextractr)

# map of the us
us <- st_as_sf(map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
us <- st_transform(us, 4326)
# transform the map into a grid
us_grid <- st_make_grid(us, n = 1000) %>% 
  st_as_sf(.) %>% 
  mutate(value = 1:n()) 
# rasterize the grid
us_star <- st_rasterize(us_grid)
# raster: from star to spatraster
r <- rast(us_star)
# exact extract
res <- exact_extract(r, us, c("mean", "sum"))
res <- bind_cols(st_drop_geometry(us), res) %>% as_tibble()
res # Result

# A tibble: 49 × 3
   ID                      mean        sum
   <chr>                  <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 alabama              316548. 187755824 
 2 arizona              377844. 504420768 
 3 arkansas             403013. 254679920 
 4 california           500085. 954256576 
 5 colorado             571636. 745238464 
 6 connecticut          680399.  44530280 
 7 delaware             572282.  14361164 
 8 district of columbia 567871.    468068.
 9 florida              145673.  90250880 
10 georgia              310336. 210169088 
# ℹ 39 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

I now try to replicate the results without asking exact extract to generate the average and total values associated to a state, but only to indicate which pixels falls within a State.
In order to make things easier, I only consider Florida.
If I compare the average and total values of pixels falling within Florida calculated by me and by exact extract in the previous exercise, things are pretty much the same:
# select Florida
fl_values <- exact_extract(r, us %>% filter(ID == "florida"))
# values of cells in Florida 
fl_values <- as_tibble(fl_values[[1]])

#Sum value of cells in florida in fl_values
sum(fl_values[, 1] * # value of the pixel
      fl_values[, 2], # portion of the pixel coverage
    na.rm = T)
[1] 90250878
#Sum value of cells in florida in res
res %>% filter(ID  == "florida") %>% pull(sum)
[1] 90250880
#Average value of cells in florida in fl_values
sum(fl_values[, 1] * # value of the pixel
      fl_values[, 2], # portion of the pixel coverage
    na.rm = T)/sum(fl_values[, 2])
[1] 145666.5
#Average value of cells in florida in res
res %>% filter(ID  == "florida") %>% pull(mean)
[1] 145673.3

I now try to replicate the same exercise, but this time I identify by my own which cells fall within Florida, and then I calculate their average and total value.
This time results are similar when calculating the average, but differ significantly when calculating the total value.
# Repeat the same exercise manually with us_grid
fl <- us %>% filter(ID == "florida")
fl_grid <- st_join(us_grid, fl) %>% 
  mutate(area = st_area(.) %>% as.numeric()) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(ID))
fl_grid_cut <- st_intersection(fl_grid, fl %>% select(-ID)) %>% 
  mutate(area_cov = st_area(.) %>% as.numeric(),
         area_cov = area_cov/area) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry()

sum(fl_grid_cut$value * fl_grid_cut$area_cov)/sum(fl_grid_cut$area_cov)
[1] 145679.3
#Average value of cells in florida in res
res %>% filter(ID  == "florida") %>% pull(mean)
[1] 145673.3

sum(fl_grid_cut$value * fl_grid_cut$area_cov )
[1] 1392929296
#Sum value of cells in florida in res
res %>% filter(ID  == "florida") %>% pull(sum)
[1] 90250880

I am clearly missing many things here.

A user noted that the problem could be related to the large area of the pixels used in my toy example. I have edited the question, reporting an example with pixels 100 times smaller (i.e., n from 10 to 1000). I have definitely improved the values obtained with the mean, but I am still far from understanding how the total value (i.e. the sum) is calculated.

The line:
us_star <- st_rasterize(us_grid)

is not an exact conversion. The resulting raster does not have the same number of cells as the input vector grid. It would be better to start with a raster populated with the appropriate values, then convert the raster into polygons.
A large pixel size could also introduce a discrepancy between the st_intesection/st_area and exact_extract. exactextract is using planar area calculations to compute the coverage fraction of each cell. With very large cells, that approach would introduce an error relative to the geodesic calculation that st_area is performing. Still, I am thinking the pixels would need to be several degrees in size before this would matter.

Thank you. This is surely informative. I have edited the question and now I am using considerably smaller pixels. I have definitely improved the values obtained with the mean, but I am still far from understanding how the total value (i.e. the sum) is calculated. Do you know why is that?
